# Creating a Group in the Right pane of File explorer

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-explorer

I have a requirement of creating a Group like favorites, Libraries, Networks etc, in the Right pane of windows File explorer, is it possible to do like this? Following Image will tells that what exactly i'm looking for;

[image: requirement]

Note :- Currently i am creating the shortcut under the Favorites area, is there any posibility to create a main Group like Favorites.

Answer (score 0):

This applies to Windows 7.

You can use libraries to view and arrange files from different locations. There are four default libraries (Documents, Music, Pictures, and Videos), but you can also create new libraries for other collections.

**To create a new library**

1. Click the **Start** button, click your user name (which opens your
   personal folder), and then, in the left pane, click **Libraries**.
2. In **Libraries**, on the toolbar, click **New library**.
3. Type a name for the library, and then press Enter.

To copy, move, or save files to a library, you must first include a folder in the library so that the library knows where to store the files. This folder automatically becomes the default save location for the library. For information about including folders and setting the default save location, see [Include folders in a library](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/include-folders-in-a-library) and [Customize a library](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/customize-a-library).

Comment: Hope that this will create a folder under Libraries section, isn't it? My question is create a group like Libraries in the left pane. See the attached image with the question, anyway thank you for the quick response

Comment: @un-lucky, gotcha. In that case, read the two links in my answer. One, or both, should have you covered.